# trap on command exit not working unless used in a function or sub-shell

Tags: bash, shell, signals, error-handling, trap

Am experimenting a bit with `trap` on invalid command return code using a sample code

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit on error
trap 'echo 'exiting..';exit' ERR
set -e

h=1
b=$((h+)) # <----- command causing the error
echo $?
echo $b
echo "end"
```

Am not able to cause the trap to occur even though there is an offending instruction. But the same if I run in a sub-shell as

```
function junk() {
h=1
b=$((h+))
echo "Exit code:$?"
echo $b
echo "end"
echo "Hello"
}

junk
```

(or) running the entire instructions in a sub-shell as

```
(h=1
b=$((h+))
echo "Exit code:$?"
echo $b
echo "end"
echo "Hello"
)
```

am able to catch the command failure and the `EXIT` catches the trap and prints the message accordingly.

Am aware of the usage of `set -e`

```
-e  errexit When set, the shell exits when a simple command in a command list exits
    non-zero (FALSE). This is not done in situations, where the exit code is already checked 
    (if, while, until, ||, &&)
```

but I can't find a proper reference where it says happens only on a sub-shell or a function or something similar.

Let me know if I am missing something basic here.

Comment: Your `trap 'echo 'exiting..';exit' ERR` doesn't nest quotes, so you're popping _out_ of quotes for the word `exiting...` and then back in again. I suspect that although this works it's not actually what you intend. I would suggest that `trap 'echo "exiting..";exit' ERR` might be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are missing is that `set -e` and sigspec `ERR` both apply to command *execution* (commands that exit with a non-zero value). What you have here with `b=$((h+))` is a *parsing* error. The command is *not* executed because it is not understood.

Why does it work in a function or sub-shell? Because this parsing error makes the containing script (be it function or a sub-shell) fail as a whole. In other words, this is not `b=$((h+))` that triggers your trap (there is no trap set in your sub-shells), this is the failure of the call to `junk` or to your subshell.

Comment: That's great! Can you provide some reference from any of the man pages about this behavior, I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: @Inian since it's not valid syntax perhaps you could explain what you would have expected `b=$((h+))` to do.

Comment: @roaima : Note sure what you meant, that line was the intended offending instruction which I enforced manually.

Comment: @roaima : Wanted a proper reference as per xhienne's answer, if the containing script either a function or a subshell could cause the failure as a whole rather than a single offending instruction

Comment: @Inian oh I see. I thought you wanted a reference to the failing command. Anyway, here is the part of the `bash` manual that describes this behavour: « _If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status [...]_ »

Comment: @roaima: Ahh! _a compound command_ is what I was looking for! Many thanks for the reference!

Comment: Thanks @roaima. I have updated my answer to mention `ERR` along with `set -e`